# How to search one string for all of the words contained in a second string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I need to check a **`string A`** for a match based on whether it contains all of the words in another **`string B`** - in whatever order.

So, let's say **`string A`** is this:

```
one two three four five
```

And **`string B`** is one of these:

```
one two three // match!
one three two // match! (order doesn't matter)
one two six // NOT A MATCH! ('six' is not found in string A)
one two three four // match!
one two three four five // match!
one two three four five seven // NOT A MATCH! ('seven' is not found in string A)
```

How would I find a match between **`string A`** and **`string B`** only if every word in **`string B`** is found in **`string A`** (regardless of the order of the words in either string and regardless of whether **`string A`** contains additional words that are not found in **`string B`**)?

I don't know if jQuery has any special features that would help with this or whether I need to do it strictly with pure JavaScript?

Comment: you have String A and String B , take each word from string B and check if it is there in String A or not , if it is not there return false , it should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// If the client has the array method **every**, this method is efficient-

```
function commonwords(string, wordlist){
    string= string.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
    wordlist= wordlist.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
    return wordlist.every(function(itm){
        return string.indexOf(itm)!= -1;
    });
}
```

**commonwords('one two three four five','one two nine');**

// If you want **any** client to handle it without a special function, 
you can 'explain' the advanced array methods-

```
Array.prototype.every= Array.prototype.every || function(fun, scope){
    var L= this.length, i= 0;
    if(typeof fun== 'function'){
        while(i<L){
            if(i in this && !fun.call(scope, this[i], i, this)) return false;
            ++i;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return null;
}
Array.prototype.indexOf= Array.prototype.indexOf || function(what, i){
    i= i || 0;
    var L= this.length;
    while(i< L){
        if(this[i]=== what) return i;
        ++i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Split the strings into arrays of words.
2. For each word in `string A`, assign `obj[word] = true;`.
3. For each word in `string B`, check if `obj[word] === true;`.  If it does not, return false.
4. Return true.

This should be trivial enough to translate into code.

Answer (score 1):

```
function compare(stringA, stringB) {
    // split for the words
    var aa = stringA.split(/\s+/), ab = stringB.split(/\s+/);
    var ha = {}, hb = {};

    // use a hash of the words
    for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i ++) ha[aa[i]] = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < ab.length; j ++) hb[ab[j]] = true;

    // compare the two sets
    for (var k in hb) if (!ha.hasOwnProperty(k)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This returns true (but should return false): `compare('', 'hasOwnProperty')`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a Set of the words in String A (Object with `true` values in JavaScript), and check if it contains each word in String B?

How are you defining "word"? Is `string.split("\\s+");` sufficient, or are you doing something fancier?

Comment: `string.split("\\s+")` works fine, yes, that's what i mean by 'word'.