# How to match for a string from an original string?

Tags: javascript

I want to match a string from an original string
**Eg :**
Assume that the orginal string is
`"THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER A LAZY DOG."`

and another string is
`"QUICK OVER A DOG"`
So If the words of the above string present in original string then it should return true.
How can I do this ?

I have used the method `indexOf(filter) > -1` 
It is working only if I give the continuous string like
**"BROWN FOX"**

 but If I give **"BROWN JUMPS"** as a string then It is not working.

```
var string_1 = "QUICK BROWN";
var string_2 = "QUICK FOX";
// this returns true
if (original.toUpperCase().indexOf(string_1) > -1) {
    console.log("true");
} else {
    console.log("false");
}

// this returns false
if (original.toUpperCase().indexOf(string_2) > -1) {
    console.log("true");
} else {
    console.log("false");
}
```

So How can I match the string from original string ?

Comment: Does the order of the words matter?

Comment: do you need the words in the original order, or does the order do not matter?

Comment: @melpomene No, the order of the words does not matter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search one string for all of the words contained in a second string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241431/how-to-search-one-string-for-all-of-the-words-contained-in-a-second-string)

Comment: @melpomene I just want that If the words of the string are present in an original string... Eg., "DOG BROWN" should also return true .

Answer (score 3):

I'd match all word characters in both strings, to get an array of words, and put the original string's words (the one to search through) into a Set. Then check whether `.every` one of the other words exists in the Set:

```js
const orig = "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER A LAZY DOG.";
// if the strings may not have any words in them at all,
// then alternate with the empty array, since the match will be null:
const origWordsSet = new Set(orig.match(/\w+/g) || []);
const verify = str => (str.match(/\w+/g) || []).every(word => origWordsSet.has(word));

console.log(
  verify("QUICK OVER A DOG"),
  verify("QUICK BROWN"),
  verify("QUICK FOX"),
  verify("FOO")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If in order, you could take `indexOf` and iterate all words by taking an index.

```js
const 
    checkInOrder = (haystack, needle, index = 0) => 
        needle.split(' ').every(w => (index = haystack.indexOf(w, index)) !== -1);
    checkWithoutOrder = (haystack, needle) => 
        needle.split(' ').every(w => haystack.includes(w));

console.log(checkInOrder("THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER A LAZY DOG.", "QUICK OVER DOG"));
console.log(checkInOrder("THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER A LAZY DOG.", "QUICK OVER some DOG"));
console.log(checkWithoutOrder("THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER A LAZY DOG.", "DOG OVER "));
console.log(checkWithoutOrder("THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER A LAZY DOG.", "DOG OVER some"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using the following array tricks. Just check if all elements of new array is in original array too.

```js
let str1='THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER A LAZY DOG';
let str2='THE FOX JUMPS';
 
let arr1=str1.split(" ");
let arr2=str2.split(" ");

console.log(arr2.filter( a => arr1.includes(a)).length===arr2.length);
```

Comment: That's the same approach as CertainPerformance's answer, only slower (yours is O(n*m)).

Comment: Thanks mate , we don’t need to worry about speed in this simple problem, just keeping it simple.please correct me if I am wrong, happy to delete it

Comment: this is simplest so like this one

Comment: But what should I do if I check for "FOX JU" and  return  true

Comment: Fox ju will return false as we are considering whole word